# Dragging from a QAbstractItemModel drops empty string

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop

I derived a custem model from `QAbstractItemModel` and implemented drag&drop support by

1. overloading a `flags()` method that returns `Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled` where applicable,
2. overloading `supportedDropActions` and
3. implementing `mimeData()` to properly return a `QMimeData` object with some string set for the `text/plain` format.

When I setup this model in a `QTreeView` and enable dragging via `setDragEnabled(true)`, I can pick items from the tree view and drag them. For example, I can drag an item and drop it onto a `QLineEdit`, which in turn will display the string that the model returned via `mimeData()`.

However, when I drag an item and drop it onto another application's widgets (such as notepad or simply a second instance of my application) an empty string gets dropped.

I found another clue using the *Drop site example* shipped with Qt: When I drag an item over it, it correctly shows that there is `text/plain` available and it even displays the string associated with it. Yet, when I drop the item I get an empty string again in the `dropEvent()`...

### Sourcecode

ssce.pro:

```
QT += core gui widgets
TARGET = ssce
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtWidgets>

struct Model: public QAbstractItemModel {
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const {
        return parent.isValid() ? 0 : 1;
    }

    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const {
        return 1;
    }

    QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const {
        return parent.isValid() ? QModelIndex() : createIndex(row, column, static_cast<void *>(0));
    }

    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &child) const {
        return QModelIndex();
    }

    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const {
        return Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled;
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
        return (role == Qt::DisplayRole) ? "Test item" : QVariant();
    }

    QStringList mimeTypes() const {
        return QStringList("text/plain");
    }

    QMimeData *mimeData(const QModelIndexList &indexes) const {
        QMimeData *d = new QMimeData();
        d->setText("hello world");
        return d;
    }

    Qt::DropActions supportedDropActions() const {
        return Qt::CopyAction;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QDialog d;
    QVBoxLayout l;

    QLineEdit e;
    l.addWidget(&e);

    QTreeView v;
    Model m;
    v.setModel(&m);
    v.setDragEnabled(true);
    l.addWidget(&v);

    d.setLayout(&l);
    d.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Description:
Run this and you can drag the item from the tree view into the line edit, it will display *hello world* then. Drop the item anywhere else, including the line edit of a second instance of the sample application, and nothing will happen.

Comment: I'd add at least the mimeData() reimplementation to the question